# JPG preview in Finder (OS 10.13.4) broken

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, high-sierra, preview, quicklook

After updating to High Sierra (10.13.4) the preview of jpg files in the finder are broken. It would appear that it is only the case with jpg's created by Adobe Illustrator (CC 2018).

[image: screenshot of finder problem]

I restarted in 'Safe Mode' and the problem is fixed, but am unable to find the source of the problem :(

I have tried clearing the QuickLook cache with 'qlmanage -r' in terminal (didn't work!)
I have tried clearing other cache, like p-ram etc... didn't work!
My next move would be to clean install OS High Sierra again, but want to avoid that :(

Hase anyone had this problem and found a solution??

Comment: `qlmanage -r` has always worked for me with any random weirdness. Anything else on https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/qlmanage.1.html any help? Is it only Ai? I only have Ps & Lr but see no issues on them.

Comment: Do the images appear garbled when you open them in Preview.app? If they look OK, try a [re-save](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/error-invalid-jpeg-marker-displays.html) and see if they open in Quicklook. You should also look at the specific settings for jpgs in Illustrator (if such a thing exists) to make sure nothing is wonky.